# Tumblr Theme: Add image to post summary

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

As you can see in this tumblr blog www.lowcoupling.com I have an index page with  6 post summaries. I'd like to add a tumbnail version of an image, for instance let me say the first image of the post, in the post summary. Is there any way in tumblr to get get a reference to an image defined within the post?